# Can Arrow brads (BN1810) be used in Stanley staple/brad guns (like TR250)?

Tags: nails

Staples seem to be widely interchangeable among stapler brands, in terms of the compatibility that is listed on the box, but brad nails are more specific.

If we are to believe the packaging, Arrow BN1810 nails (5/8", 18 gauge) can only be used in a few Arrow guns, whereas a Stanley TR250 calls specifically for model SWKBN625 brads: also 5/8" long, 18 gauge.

How different are these, and are they really not interchangeable? Do they have some key dimensions that are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal testing shows that Arrow BN1810 brad nails load into a Stanley TR250 stapler and work without any problem.

Comment: is this personal experience, or is there a source you can link to?

Comment: @mac Indeed, I did the experiment. If a source could have been found easily, I wouldn't have asked the question. I hope it helps future visitors.

Comment: Either way, it's a good question and answer. I've taken the liberty to edit to clarify.